# When should you choose a random forest over a decision tree?

Tags: random-forest, cart

What criteria would make you decide to use a random forest over a decision tree? How do we decide when a decision tree is not sufficient?

Comment: While this is admittedly broad, the existence of upvoted answers suggests it is somewhat answerable. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Random forest is generally a better model if the goal is for prediction. In other words, we'd want to reduce the variance of the model. For example, the built-in OOB validation error rate is handy and can be efficiently implemented.

However, we prefer a single decision tree if the goal is for exploratory analysis. We often just want to understand how the data is related in a tree hierarchy structure.

Comment: I use a forest for both.  The forest gives variable importance which is very useful.  I use trees derived from forests in actual logic because they have the strength of extreme simplicity without the weakness of poor generalization.  I also use trees to communicate ideas to non-technical people, like management.  They like models they feel like they understand.  Make it the universally simplest model that still holds the information.

Answer (score 2):

Decision Tree is a stand alone model, while a Random Forest is an ensemble of Decision Trees. Decision Tree is a weak learner. It is prone to over fitting (high variance) and is highly dependent on the training sample. Since a RF consists of a huge number of decision trees, it adds regularization and hence becomes a strong learner.

For more information about why RF are used over Decision Trees, check out my personal blog [Decision Trees, Random Forests and XGBoost](http://sujayskumar.blogspot.in/2017/02/decision-trees-rf-and-xgboost.html)

But the thumb rule is, if the decision tree itself is giving acceptable results for your use case, a random forest would be over kill. This is analogous to a situation where, if a linear regression model is providing acceptable results, do not build a deep neural network.

Comment: Hello. Please make sure that you don't advertise your own blog so much - it'll get flagged as spam. It's okay in moderation, but please make sure to mention that it's yours and that it's not the *only* thing you're posting. Also, please make sure that it's actually relevant to what you're answering :). Thanks.

Comment: @Mithrandir Thank you for the pointers. I have no intentions of advertising my blog. I genuinely believe that the blog post contains more information in much more detail than what can be posted here. I did answer the question asked. Regarding the attribution, is the edit enough? Thanks!

Comment: Build up is great.  I think a linear regressor is to a NN what a CART is to a forest.  If I was starting, I would start with the forest to look at non-linearity and dimensionality reduction, then try to move toward the linear or generalized linear model.